# Examples of bundles with minimal fibers

Tags: riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces, submersions

There is a result of Chen

> https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00605-007-0451-y
>
> A Riemannian submersion $\pi : F \hookrightarrow (E,g) \to B$ with minimal fibers $F$ and such that $g$ has negative sectional curvature is such that the induced metric on $F$ has negative scalar curvature.

I would like very much to know: is there any explicit example of bundles of this kind?

Moreover, are there any Riemannian submersions with torus as fibers or with any other aspherical manifold as fiber, such that the fibers are minimal?

Comment: For your second question, you could just take a trivial projection of the $n$-torus with the flat metric onto one of its $S^1$ factors. For the first, you could take a look at mapping tori of pseudo-Anosov diffeomorphisms of surfaces of genus greater than or equal to two, although I couldn't tell you at a glance whether the fibers are minimal in this case.

Comment: nice comment @RohilPrasad, I just a little concerned about the examples to the second question. It would be nice to have a basis of dimension at least two, but this could be done by projecting on lower dimensional torus factors, right?

Comment: Exactly, a standard projection $T^3 \to T^2$, for example would also have minimal fibers. An update on the first question: I consulted Ben Lowe and he mentioned that in fact it is a conjecture of Thurston that closed, fibered hyperbolic 3-manifolds do not admit codimension-one foliations with minimal fibers. So one will probably have to look elsewhere for examples.